# How to view and download doc, pdf, ppt, zip, rar, in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Here is My view in laravel

```
@if($status->type == 1)
      <a href="{{ $status->image_url }}"></a>
         <img src="{{asset('status_images/'.$status->image_url)}}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;">
     @endif
```

i want to view here also docx, ppt, pdf, zip and rar file and also want to download in laravel 5.2 what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel views you can use the [helper asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) to link to assets of any kind: jpg, png, docx, ppt, pdf, zip, rar,... but you only can see the assets that can be rendered by the navigator, like images or PDF files. You can't see zip or rar files, so you have to download this kind of assets.

For example,

```
<script src="{{asset('/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

will generate

```
<link href="http://example.com/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The "assets" folder is inside the "public" folder (your public path).

You can use it with another asset types: docx, ppt, pdf, zip, rar,...

In Laravel controllers you can use the [download method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#file-downloads) in the HTTP response to download the asset. For example, a PDF resource:

```
$basepath = storage_path() . '/pdf';
$fileName = 'invoice_20160729.pdf';
if (file_exists($basepath . '/' . $fileName)) {
    return response()->download($basepath . '/' . $fileName);
}
```

Comment: i can't use helper asset sir... plese help me, what should to write in my view.??